# How to compute p-value for quadratic fit of (25) discrete data points?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, p-value, nonlinear-regression

**Preamble**: I've had a couple of statistics courses @ uni, but can't really say I got "hooked" (I read NNT's Black Swan *before* starting the degree :), hence the depth of my statistical knowledge remained (so far) rather shallow and mechanical, lacking deeper insight and a "feeling" for the matter; maybe I'm just lacking real-world practice and application...

I've got a set of data (only 25 data points); in `gnumeric` I chose a "quadratic fit" (see for instance [here](http://jongarvin.com/wp-content/uploads/MDM4U/Stats_Gnumeric.pdf)) which returns an $R^2$ value of $0.39$ and a quadratic fit expression of $-0.13 x^2 + 4.65 x - 0.57$ (rounded).

Regarding *how to report results*, from [here](http://staff.bath.ac.uk/pssiw/stats2/page2/page3/page3.html) I gather that three things generally ought to be reported (for simple regressions and the like):

- the **R-squared** value (goodness of fit *viz.* coefficient of determination)
- the equation (though I don't think this is always informative/interesting)
- the **p-value** (regarding the statistical *significance* of the fit), where it'd be enough to write one of two things in a report: "p < .05" or "n.s." (not significant).

What I'm missing from `gnumeric`'s output for *quadratic* regressions is the **p-value** (this can easily be obtained for linear cases, though). Thus, I was wondering whether a $\chi^2$ goodness-of-fit test would help (after classifying the continuous fit values according to the discrete, original 25 data points). Barking up the wrong alley?

Comment: On my system I've currently got installed Matlab/Octave, Gretl, R and spreadsheet applications (of which I'm most comfortable with the former and the latter); if it's a simple (if but tedious) calculation which can be performed for the 25 points "on paper": how? If it's sth for one of the software packages: how?

Comment: which p-value do you want? A p-value always refers to a statistical test and a statistical tests always refers to a null hypothesis. So which null-hypothesis do you want to test? "the fit is significant" is not a null hypothesis.

Comment: @MaartenBuis my question -- and I -- am really naïve: I just want to do "the correct thing": e.g., to *answer* whether the fit is significant. Is that the wrong question to ask/answer? If I've only got 25 data points, did a fit (which looks good and R2 of 0.4 is "not *too* bad", is it?) and additionally want to say *something* about the (statistical) "significance" of the fit (so that this exercise at least looks a bit more sophisticated...), how? -- Or is there "no such thing" as a "statistically significant fit" ? (incidentally, Google returns in excess of 100,000 hits for that query phrase)

Comment: ...to add to the list above: QtiPlot/Origin.

Comment: @MaartenBuis how about this for the null: $H_0$: both the 25 data points and the fit belong to the same (a different) distribution?

Comment: Please stop trying to use statistical terms; you're misusing them in a way that's making it harder to figure out what you actually want. Without using the word 'significant' or hypothesis (and preferably using only ordinary English words if possible) can you say what it is you're trying to figure out? Are you trying to see if a quadratic model is better in some sense than a linear one? Are you trying to see if the quadratic coefficient is further from zero than you'd expect with random variation from a linear model?  ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... Or are you trying to see if the whole quadratic fit is such that it's unlikely to have happened if the data were just random noise around a constant?

Comment: @Glen_b For my thesis, I'm plotting a relationship between X and Y. Next, I'm calculating-and-plotting a linear fit and a quadratic/polynomial fit. Both return an $R^2$ value. For the linear fit, additionally I obtain a p-value ($H_0$: linear parameter = $0$). This tells me that the relationship is significantly linear. For the polynomial fit I don't (yet) know how to get a p-value (or sth equivalent). Possibly I'm after *not* actually after the p-value but rather the F-value, as there's both a linear *and* a quadratic term in the polynomial fit. Am happy to learn, plz point out my mistakes!

Comment: [This](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statcurvreg.html) seem promising/helpful.

Comment: @Glen_b I think you're 2nd comment is what I'm after: comparing the polynomial fit to "white noise".

Comment: One thing that I like to do is look at the 95% confidence interval around the parameter estimates.  If the range is tight it tells me something about the expected variation in the parameter given the data.  And I am not a stats guy either.  As someone who loves science I know that the more that stats can be communicated in human language there will be more higher quality technical results that inform improvement and growth in the field.  I like that idea.  (lots)

Answer (score 5):

Since you say you have R I'll discuss it in terms of R. It can also be done in Excel, Matlab and according to pages I can see on the web, the regression tool in gnumeric will do multiple linear regression, so it should let you do this calculation.

The F-value is a test statistic, the [p-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) tells you about the probability of a test statistic at least that extreme occurring when H0 is true. In R, the p-value for the quadratic + linear terms together against a mean-only model is found right in the summary of the model.

Here's how to do a linear model in R (the `cars` data is built in, so this code should work as is):

`summary(lm(speed~dist,data=cars))`

Here's a quadratic model done two different ways

`summary(lm(speed~dist+I(dist^2),data=cars))`

`summary(lm(speed~poly(dist,2),data=cars))`

[The second approach sets up orthogonal polynomials and is usually preferable, though it's somewhat harder to get the actual quadratic equation out (though not so hard to draw the fit), so if the actual equation matters to you, you may not want to try it the `poly` way first up.]

Here's the results for the linear model:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  8.28391    0.87438   9.474 1.44e-12 ***
dist         0.16557    0.01749   9.464 1.49e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.156 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6511,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6438 
F-statistic: 89.57 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 1.49e-12
```

The `dist` row shows the p-value for the contribution of `dist`. The last line shows the p-value for the contributions of all terms after the constant (intercept); the p-value is the same in this case because there is only the `dist` term).

Here's the results for the quadratic model:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.1439610  1.2954573   3.971 0.000244 ***
dist         0.3274544  0.0547392   5.982 2.86e-07 ***
I(dist^2)   -0.0015284  0.0004939  -3.095 0.003316 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.907 on 47 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7101,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6978 
F-statistic: 57.57 on 2 and 47 DF,  p-value: 2.299e-13
```

The `I(dist^2)` row (you need the `I(.)`!) in the table gives the p-value for testing whether just the size of the quadratic coefficient is random noise around a linear model, while the last row gives the p-value for the F-test of the quadratic+linear model against the constant mean (intercept-only), testing if it could be just due to noise. The `dist` row is the p-value for its contribution *fitted last*, which isn't terribly interesting in the case of fitting polynomials. The orthogonal version obviates that issue; with orthogonal predictors the results are the same no matter what order they're in, so interpretation is easier (and the calculations are more stable).

It's certainly possible to fit this by hand; there are a couple of ways to do it, but to go through everything down to the calculation of p-values is rather lengthy.

If gnumeric will give you the error sum of squares (which you can compute from the data and the fitted model anyway), you can compute the F statistic from that; if it has a function for the F-distribution (the CDF), then you should be able to get the p-value as well.